# Multiple sed substitutions - what's wrong

Tags: sed

The idea is to apply both these substitutions to the pattern space

```
sed -re 's/\v\s+/\t/g' -re 's/[(]([^()]+)[)]\s*\t/\1\t/' movies.list
```

gives me what I think is a syntax error.

Here is some test data (although it won't match the first pattern.

```
& The Oriental Groove, Yacine   "Els matins a TV3" (2004)
& Vinícius, João Bosco  Show da Virada (2011)   Teleton 2009 (2009) Teleton 2012 (2012) "Eliana" (2009)
'77 Big Smoker Pig  "Pop ràpid" (2011)
'Ariffin, Syaiful   Desire (2014/III)
'Aruhane        Shaping Bamboo (1979)
'Atu'ake, Taipaleti When the Man Went South (2014)
```

Comment: Drop the second `-r` and see if that helps.

Comment: It did and I prefer this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `-r` flag is causing the problem. At that point in the argument processing you can't be using that flag apparently. Just drop it.

```
sed -re 's/\v\s+/\t/g' -e 's/[(]([^()]+)[)]\s*\t/\1\t/' movies.list
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `;` between your substitution commands:

```
sed -re 's/\v\s+/\t/g; s/[(]([^()]+)\s*\t/\1\t/' movies.list
```

Comment: I tried this before posting and unexpectedly ended up with output routed to the screen from the shell script I was running, so I went with Etan's solution, but thank you for answering.